# grails pdf plugin: save pdf to folder

Tags: pdf, grails, plugins

In my Grails project I use the pdf plugin (http://grails.org/plugin/pdf) to render pdfs. I would like to know if it is possible to automatically save the generated pdf in a certain folder. Folders must be the ones present in remote server where app runs.
In gsp page I use the g:pdfLink tag as follows:

```
<g:pdfLink class="pdf"   pdfController="patient" pdfAction="surgeryModule" pdfId="${patientInstance?.id}" ></g:pdfLink>
```

and method surgeryModule is as follows:

```
def surgeryModule(Long id){

    def patientInstance = Patient.get(id)

    if (!patientInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'patient.label', default: 'Patient'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

}
```

when invoked it shows the browser window in which user can open or save file, but I would like to also store pdf automatically in one of the server's folders.

Comment: The [rendering](http://gpc.github.io/grails-rendering/) plugin might be a better fit if you can switch to it because it provides services to write to an output stream

Comment: You could even use the export plugin http://grails.org/plugin/export, The plugin which you are currently using was last updated in 2010.

Comment: it seems that export plugin does not allow to save pdfs in remote folders...am I wrong?because I need to store pdfs in remote server folders